# How to see values of member variables in WinDbg?

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg

The command `x` never really works for me. I can do `dv` which shows the local variables but doesn't show member variables of class. I have been relying on watch locals variables window to see those values but how can see them through `x` command?

For example I have a variable in module `Db!MyRecordSet::m_strQuery` how can I see value of m_strQuery?

I particularly like to use wildcard to see all member variables like this:

```
x Db!MyRecordSet m_*
```

But it returns without doing anything or displaying any message..it just returns like nothing happened.

Comment: There is an `x` command (= Examine Symbols), it just never works or I am missing its syntax!? I don't know how to access/mention the member variable. It's in a module, than a class and its member of that class.

Comment: It does something different: it is finding symbols. Once found, use `dt` (display type).

Comment: @ThomasWeller It does find functions but why does it not find member variables which are also symbols

Comment: I am mostly working with release build

Answer (score 2):

If I get the MASM documentation right, the syntax with two colons should be ok for symbols:

> Use two colons (::) or two underscores (__) to indicate the members of a class

In a release build, you might need to consider that the compiler was able to optimize the member variable away.

Other than that, the `x` command can only show the symbols itself and does not map it to a memory address, therefore I think you're looking for the `dt` (**d**isplay **t**ype) command, with either

```
dt -r Db!MyRecordSet <address>
```

for recursive display or expanded to a given hierarchy level

```
dt Db!MyRecordSet... <address>
```

for a 3-level tree.

Example, cited from WinDbg's documentation (because I don't have an example at hand):

```
0:000> dt nt!_PEB CriticalSectionTimeout.. 7ffdf000 
   +0x070 CriticalSectionTimeout   :  0xffffe86d`079b8000
      +0x000 LowPart                  : 0x79b8000
      +0x004 HighPart                 : -6035
      +0x000 u                        :
         +0x000 LowPart                  : 0x79b8000
         +0x004 HighPart                 : -6035
      +0x000 QuadPart                 : -25920000000000
```

Another option could be the C++ evaluation

```
??@@c++(variable->member)
```

Comment: the `x` doesn't really show member variables still and the wild card doesn't work on `dt` either. I know it should but don't know why it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jigarme/2007/10/28/how-to-look-at-value-of-structure-object-who-is-member-of-class-object-while-debugging-in-windbg/

check this out.

simply the command is like:
dt -b modulename!classname 0xffffffff`xxxxxxxx memberofclass

Comment: Thanks for posting. Will try this out next time around.

Answer (score 0):

There is now the dx command.

Here I'm in a c++ function with a local _picture object; to display one member ("field"?) I used this:

> 0:000> dx _picture.rows
>
> ```
> _picture.rows    : 400 [Type: int]
> ```

And here is the result of dv, showing that I actually have two picture objects in the function:

> 0:000> dv
>
> ```
>    _picture2 = class cv::Mat
>    _picture = class cv::Mat
> ```

Comment: you should qualify your answer with reference to newer releases    dx wasn't available back then  when the question was asked